# Как быть с GetSysColor?

Tags: c++, winapi

В Win10+ microsoft решила отказаться от ряда цветов?

Непонимаю, а где теперь брать эти цвета?
Бысто не получается найти ответ, microsoft ещё не добавили на страницу что с этим делать. Что получается, ряд программ не будут корректно работать под win10? Как по-новому получать цвета заголовка, меню, других цветовых параметров?

Страница microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так полагаю что какое-то время там будет некая заглушка. А вообще мелкософты не любят отказываться от легаси. В крайнем случае есть режим совместимости для очень бородатого софта, да и виртуалки некто не отменял...

Comment: Я пишу софтину, хочу задействовать цветовую палитру. Вижу написано not supported, и... вроде почитал их сайт.. не вижу альтернативы GetSysColor, если эту функцию отменили, должна быть какая-то другая, которая даёт правильные цвета.

Comment: CodeGear совсем недавно выпустили Delphi 11, и там функция `ColorToRGB` которая так-же обрабатывет системные цвета, досихпор использует `Result := GetSysColor(Color and $000000FF)` не думаю что мы умнее их и они не подумали об Deprecated Variable.

Comment: Цвета заголовков, меню и прочего утратили актуальность с переходом на отрисовку элементов интерфейса посредством скинов в WindowsXP. В современном WinUI цвета задаются через темы. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources Еще по идее "не поддерживается" относится к приложениям, у которых в манифесте объявлена поддержка Windows10, а более старые будут получать значения по-прежнему. Так что совместимость не должна поломаться.